# Autodetect spell-checker language in Chrome using custom rules?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, language, spell-check

In the Chrome web-browser (current version: 32.0.1700.41 m Aura), how can I have Chrome AUTOMATICALLY detect the spell checker language for input fields, using sets of custom rules, for example:

1. Depending from the current domain, for example:
   *.de // changes spell-checker language to German
   englishforum.com // changes spell-checker language to English
   etc. etc.
2. Autodetect using a smart algorithm (used when not covered by #1): Internally uses the activated spell checker languages and tests which language produces the least amount of errors, then changes the spell checking language to this language.

Is there a Google Chrome extension for this?

Comment: I know there's no solution in the "duplicate" thread, but it has the appropriate resources to check and determine if they will work or if the optimal solution is released or still under development.

Comment: I have added it to:
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=5102#c86

Comment: Admins: Should I delete this question because of its assumed duplicated character?

Comment: I'm not an admin, but it's up to you. If you feel the question is no longer in need of an answer, you can delete it. Right now, there's only 1 vote to close (mine). If there are 5, it will close on its own. It's possible an extension exists that I'm not aware of and maybe it will show up as an answer.